# Get default value for date

Tags: sql, sql-server

According to [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) the *default value* of a date in SQL Server is

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00
```

Can I call the default value in any way? For instance like this

```
select isnull(date_column, default(date_column))
from my_table
```

Comment: I think 1/1/1900 is the default date time value when if youre passing as a NULL parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT DefaultDate = CAST(0 AS DATETIME)
```

<kbd>[sql-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6813/0)</kbd>

If you need a `DATE` you can cast it also:

```
SELECT DefaultDate = CAST(CAST(0 AS DATETIME) AS DATE)
```

<kbd>[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6816/0)</kbd>

Comment: interestingly : you can't do: select cast(0 as datetime2) or select cast(0 as date)

Comment: @Tim: I tried that with  `date` and it did not work. it works with `datetime` - interesting.

Answer (score 3):

```
select MinimumDate = cast(dateadd(d, 0, 0) as date)
```